# Custom Progress Bar with Animation List

Tags: android, progress-bar, iprogressdialog

I want to create a progress bar which should show moving images effect. for that I have created an animation list and have saved in my drawables folder in res. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p_one" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p_two" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p_three" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p_threesix" android:duration="150" />

</animation-list>
```

After that I have used this drawable like this: for my ProressBar Drawable

```
  <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateOnly="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_anim"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Problem: Nothing is displaying when I run this code. Why ? 
When I use any single image instead of the animation-list drawable, then it is displayed correctly. Is there any other to do this ?

Comment: make `android:duration="250"` and remove    `android:indeterminate="true"`

Comment: Is this the solution ?????? @MD

Comment: Not a solution just a Patch. It's working fine with my side...

Comment: No Effect @MD. Please check

Comment: read `AnimationDrawable` documentation and you will find out how to run the animation.

Comment: wow. thank you @pskink. You are awesome

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `android:oneshot="false"` like below in `<animation-list ..>` attribute

```
<animation-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
   ...
</animation-list>
```

`android:oneshot="false"` is

> Boolean. "true" if you want to perform the animation once; "false" to loop the animation.

Android developer link for [Frame animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

Answer (score 0):

Similar strange problems here, I tried two different device, A worked very well, B showed two images in horizontal, I add `<clip>` in `<item>` , A became not working, B worked very well, so...better not to use `<animation-list>` in progressBar...